# How do I replace multiple Hex codes in JMeter?

Tags: javascript, jmeter, hex, decode

I have a JMeter script in which I need to replace some Hex code:

**&#x2b -> +**
**&#x3d -> =**

This is not a new problem, and I have seen various solutions.

**Example:**

```js
${__javaScript(decodeURIComponent('${SAMLResponse}'))}
```

None of the ones I have tried (including the one above) work for me.

I can do it successfully in Gatling and in LoadRunner, but so far not in JMeter Version 5.3

In Gatling I use a transform string:

.check(regex(""""(?<=SAMLResponse" type="hidden" value=")(.*)(?=")""").transform(str => str.replace("=","=")).transform(str => str.replace("+","+")).saveAs("SAMLResponse"))

**Note:** stackOverflow is automatically converting the Hex code I just typed. I am really not trying to convert a plus to a plus or an equals to an equals.

Using syntax like this:

**${__javaScript("${c_SAMLResponse_Raw}".split('+').join('+'),c_SAMLResponse)}**

In a **JSR223 javascript PreProcessor**, I can get things to work for one Hex code, e.g., **&#x2b** converting to **+**, but not for two different Hex codes.

Answer (score 0):

1. Replacing individual values is not something you should be normally doing when converting hex string to ascii string, if you still want to proceed with JavaScript - here is a [sample solution](https://www.w3resource.com/javascript-exercises/javascript-string-exercise-28.php)

   ```
   function hex_to_ascii(str1)
    {
       var hex  = str1.toString();
       var str = '';
       for (var n = 0; n < hex.length; n += 2) {
           str += String.fromCharCode(parseInt(hex.substr(n, 2), 16));
       }
       return str;
    }
   ```
2. [Since JMeter 3.1 it's recommended to use JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) language for any form of scripting, an example [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) which does the trick for you would be something like:

   ```
   ${__groovy(new String(org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Hex.decodeHex(vars.get('c_SAMLResponse_Raw').replaceAll('&#x'\,''))),SAMLResponse)}
   ```

   Demo:

   [image: ${__groovy(new String(org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Hex.decodeHex(vars.get('c_SAMLResponse_Raw').replaceAll('&#x'\,''))),SAMLResponse)}]

   More information: [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)